# Find files with Julian days in a specific range in their names

Tags: linux, find

I have a list of files that contain a Julian calendar date in them.
Examples: `XXX_YY_AB21123.TXT`, `XXX_YY_AB21124.TXT` etc.
I have hundreds of them for the year.
I need a way to search for the files based on the names and only return the ones for a specific range.

Example:
Return all filenames that have the Julian date embedded in the name between 60 and 90 (Mar 2021)
`XXX_YY_AB21060` thru `XXX_YY_AB21090`

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need to get the Julian date for a particular day, you can use `date`'s `%j` format and if your `date` is the GNU implementation or compatible, use `-d` to convert it from another format:

```
$ date -d "2021/03/01" +%j
060
```

Once you know that, you can use globs and brace expansion to achieve what you want:

```
$ shopt -s nullglob  # prevent unmatched globs from returning verbatim
$ printf '%s\n' *_*_*{060..090}.TXT
XXX_YY_AB21060.TXT
XXX_YY_AB21061.TXT
XXX_YY_AB21062.TXT
XXX_YY_AB21063.TXT
XXX_YY_AB21064.TXT
XXX_YY_AB21065.TXT
[...]
```

Comment: Thanks. That did what I needed!

Answer (score 1):

In `zsh`:

```
print -rC1 -- **/*AB21<60-90>.txt(N)
```

Would `print` `r`aw on `1` `C`olumn the list of filenames that end with `AB21` followed by a decimal number in the range 60 to 90 followed by `.txt` in or below the current working directory (omitting hidden ones).

To compute the range from a given `Mar 2021`-like representation, you can do:

```
month='Mar 2021'

zmodload zsh/datetime

# Mar-2021 to epoch (for first day in that month):
TZ=UTC0 strftime -r -s start '%b %Y' $month

# month after in 2021-04 format obtained by adding 35 days:
TZ=UTC0 strftime    -s t     %Y-%m   $(( start + 35 * 86400 ))

# convert that to epoch time (of the first day of month after)
TZ=UTC0 strftime -r -s t     %Y-%m   $t

# convert both to YYJJJ
TZ=UTC0 strftime    -s start %y%j    $start
TZ=UTC0 strftime    -s end   %y%j    $(( t - 86400 ))
range="<$start-$end>"

print -rC1 -- **/*AB$~range.txt(N)
```